# Accessing files from the project folder of a WP app

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xna, windows-phone-8, xna-4.0

I'm new to Windows Phone development and I'm trying to do a simple training app.

I want my app to load some audio files that I've put into a folder inside the project.

Here's a short snippet:

```
private void LoadSound(String SoundFilePath, out SoundEffect Sound)
    {

        // For error checking, assume we'll fail to load the file.
        Sound = null;
        try
        {                
            // Holds informations about a file stream.                
            StreamResourceInfo SoundFileInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(SoundFilePath, UriKind.Relative));
```

My folder structure is something like

```
- Project
    - Kits
        - TestKit_128
            - Bass_126.wav
```

and calling

```
Button.setSound("Kits\\TestKit_128\\bass_126.wav");
```

throws a `System.NullReferenceException` because the path is not found when the URI is created. (At least I think so!)

What should I do?

Is there any way to load files from a folder in the project or to copy them into the IsolatedStorage when I run the app for the first time?

Thanks

EDIT:

I've just opened the XAP file with WinRar and there's no "Kits" folder so I guess that my problem is how to make it add the folder to the XAP file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to add the folder and the file to your project (i assume you are using Visual Studio). Try rightclick on your solution and add an existing object (in this case your wav file).

Comment: This worked. With Java you can just copy&paste contents, I didn't know that I needed to add them within Visual Studio. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the build action of the wav file to "Content"? Right click on the WAV file --> properties --> build action == content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("Kits/TestKit_128/bass_126.wav", UriKind.Relative);//Above the Kits folder only the project itself. 
        StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = sr.Stream)
            {
                //working here with your data image or wav or whatever you want from URI
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
```

This is for resource inside project and working good for me. Also prevoius note about "Content" is right, it wouldn't work without it. I think the problem is double-slashes in address.